# How to update content type document template from templates list?

Tags: content-type, document-template

I have a single list at SharePoint root that contains document templates for content types ([C scenario](http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2011/02/using-document-templates-with-lists-and-content-types-in-sharepoint/)). This works and the template is being associated to child content types in lists.

Now i added some new fields and i need to add these fields to document as quick parts. But the quick parts doesn't list these new fields. However when i open list settings, i see that new fields for content types are deployed properly - the fields are associated with the content type and the list.

So i suppose word 2007 doesn't re-read this content type information into document. I'v tried opening document, doing modifications and saving it, hoping that the content type information will update, but it won't.

So what is the proper way to update document template after updating content type?
Using WSS 3.0

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download the new CT template in order for the quick parts fields to show. Your new fields wont have been mapped to the existing CT so you need to download the standard, update that with your layout, then add that as the CT Template.

:)